# Is there a way to get Program Dependency Graph of a binary with angr?

Tags: control-flow-graph, angr

I have seen that with angr, one can get Control and Data Dependency Graphs of binaries. But, I couldn't find anything related with Program Dependency Graphs (PDG). I am new to this topic, and my own implementation of a PDG generator wouldn't work bug free. I wanted to be sure that what I am looking for isn't already implemented with another name.

I have tried to use Backwards Slicing, but I am not sure if that is what I am looking for.

Comment: This question needs opinion, not answer